# Dialog is not a function (how to display custom dialog)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display on my web application a custom dialog. So I'm building this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     var mappaRisposte = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.mappaRisposte));
    ConfirmDialog('Are you sure');

    function ConfirmDialog(message) {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
            .html('<div><h6>' + message + '?</h6></div>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: 'Delete message',
                zIndex: 10000,
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 'auto',
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function () {
                        // $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');                                
                        // $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                        $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');

                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    No: function () {
                        $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');

                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

These are the external library

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <!---->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So if I try to execute this page, I can see this:
[image]

But if I try to call ConfirmDialog function from another js function in this mode:

```
function endFirstPartSummary() {
        ConfirmDialog('Are you sure');
        var parolaChiave = document.getElementById("tParolaChiave").value;
        //alert(parolaChiave);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Questionario/endFirstPartSummary',
            data: { "json": JSON.stringify(parolaChiave)},
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                //TODO: Add whatever if you want to pass a notification back
                location.href='@Url.Action("PageRingraziamento", "PageRingraziamento")'
            },
            error: function (error) {
                //TODO: Add some code here for error handling or notifications
                //alert("Il nome di fantasia indicato è già stato utilizzato, inventane un altro");

                document.getElementById("tParolaChiave").value = "";
            }
        });
    }
```

I have this error from console:

```
TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).html(...).dialog is not a function
```

Comment: try using `$("#dialog").dialog('open');`

Comment: I have update my code. In particular error function. In my endFirstPartSummary() function I called ConfirmDialog(); and in this case I getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you try using the very same dialog object twice, but on the second attempt you are getting an error.

Try saving the instance global (not inside an function), like:

```
const myDialog = $("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

and reuse it like:

```
myDialog.dialog("close"); // or maybe: myDialog.close();
```

At the moment you are using "$(this).dialog("close");" in the context of an function. So "this" is the function, not the dialog.